How to optimize query performance in GridDB for large time-series datasets?
I’m working on a project that involves managing large time-series datasets in GridDB. Currently, I’m experiencing significant query latency issues as the dataset size grows. While GridDB performs well with smaller datasets, as the dataset size has increased, certain queries have become slower than expected.
Details About the Problem
Here are some specifics to help contextualize the issue:

Dataset Size: 50 million records (approximately 200GB of data).

Query Performance: My current query takes 10 seconds to execute when filtering data over a 1-month range. Ideally, I’d like this to complete in under 2 seconds.

Hardware: Running on a 16-core CPU with 32GB RAM and SSD storage.


Example Query
Here’s an example of the query I’m using:
SELECT AVG(temperature), MAX(humidity)
FROM sensor_data
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-31'
AND location = 'warehouse-1';
What I’ve Tried
To address the performance issues, I’ve attempted the following steps:

Indexing: Created an index on the timestamp and location columns.

Partitioning: Divided the data by month using GridDB’s container partitioning feature.

Resource Allocation: Adjusted memory settings for the query engine in GridDB.
Despite these efforts, I haven’t seen a noticeable improvement in query performance.


Questions

Are there additional optimizations I can apply to the query or container configuration in GridDB to handle this scale more efficiently?

Is it normal for a 10-second query time on a dataset of this size, or am I missing something in my GridDB setup?


Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You need a tree-based index on two columns, first location, then timestamp, to support this kind of filtering.
container.create_index(["location", "timestamp"])

